# How can I mark changes in column value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL, Version 11.3. I have to export data from a table into excel for analysis.  I can use \copy for this. Is there a way to write the select so that a blank line appears whenever the value in a particular column changes? The column is named common_id. This can be the same for multiple records. I can sort on that column. But I would also like to mark a change in the value when I export to excel. Assuming the value in common_id is 1 (for 3 records), 2 (for 2 records) and 3 (for 2 records) the output would be
1
1
1

2
2

3
3

It is possible to to write a program. But wondering if it is possible to do this directly in SQL.

Comment: It is possible, but not simple. Use a simple `ORDER BY` in SQL and insert the empty line with procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, but it's definitely not simple.

```
with data as (
    select * from (values (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3), (3)) v(a)
), changed_rows as (
    select a, 
           a - lag(a, 1)  OVER (ORDER BY a) as changed, 
          row_number() over (order by a) 
    from data
), with_nulls as (
    select a, 
           row_number 
    from changed_rows 
    union all 
    select null, 
           row_number 
    from changed_rows 
    where changed = 1 
    order by row_number, a nulls first
)
select a from with_nulls;
 a
---
 1
 1
 1

 2
 2

 3
 3
(9 rows)
```

The basic idea is to use lag() to figure out where the data have changed.  The output from the changed_rows CTE looks like this:

```
 a | changed | row_number
---+---------+------------
 1 |         |          1
 1 |       0 |          2
 1 |       0 |          3
 2 |       1 |          4
 2 |       0 |          5
 3 |       1 |          6
 3 |       0 |          7
(7 rows)
```

We select all of the a column from that CTE and union all with null, row_number where changed = 1.  If we order that with nulls first, we get the answer.

EDIT: simplified it a bit